# Can not start Julia REPL with v1.6 and latest Julia VS Code Extension

Tags: julia

I am trying to start a Julia REPL session in VS Code. I launched VS Code, went to the command palette, and tried to run the "Start Julia REPL" command. However, nothing shows up. I can successfully launch Julia from my terminal via the `julia` keyword. I also double-checked my executable path and it looks right. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the issue was that I was running the most recent version of the Julia VS Code extension with Julia 1.6. My `settings.json` file had an environment path as well as an executable path. As soon as I removed the line for the environment path and restarted VS Code, the issue was resolved.